# JTree Lazy Load Expand

Tags: java, swing

Hope you are doing fine.

I have a JTree which I load lazily using database query (each node). I have a button on the screen and when user clicks the button I perform some `insert/update/delete` in database and then add the model back in `Jtree` with only root and its immediate children using an SQL (this collapses the tree and selection and all expanded nodes collapse which is expected since it is a lazily loaded tree)

What I want to accomplish is before user clicks button to `insert/update/delete`, I read all the expanded state and save it in  memory then when I re-initialize the `JTree` I loop through those expanded children and call `jtree.expandPath` but it does not expand the nodes :(.

I even added a `TreeWillExpandListener` and in `treeWillExpand` event I added code to get the children of the node from database and I see that query does get executed to get the childreen but `JTree` still shows up as collapsed.

I really need your help. Please advise. Here is the code snippet.

```
package marketdatagui;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;


public class StressGroupModel
    implements TreeModel,Serializable, Cloneable
{
    protected EventListenerList listeners;

    private static final Object LEAF = new Serializable() { };

    private Map map;

    private NodeData root;

    private class NodeData{
        String id;
        String name;

        public String toString(){
            return name;
        }
    }

    public StressGroupModel()
    {
        this.root = new NodeData();
        root.id = "Root";
        root.name = "Root";

        this.listeners = new EventListenerList();

        this.map = new HashMap();

        List rootChildren = new ArrayList();

        NodeData d1 = new NodeData();
        d1.id = "5000007";
        d1.name = "Name5000007";

        rootChildren.add(d1);

        NodeData d2 = new NodeData();
        d2.id = "10000054";
        d2.name = "Name10000054";

        rootChildren.add(d2);
        map.put(root.id, rootChildren);
    }


    public Object getRoot()
    {
        return root;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf(Object node)
    {
        return map.get(node) == LEAF;
    }

    public int getChildCount(Object node)
    {
        List children = children(node);

        if (children == null)
            return 0;

        return children.size();
    }

    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index)
    {
        return children(parent).get(index);
    }

    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child)
    {
        return children(parent).indexOf(child);
    }

    protected List children(Object node)
    {
        NodeData s = (NodeData)node;

        Object value = map.get(s.id);

        if (value == LEAF)
            return null;

        List children = (List)value;

        if (!"Root".equals(s.id))
        {
            String[][] dbData = getChildren(s.id);

            if (dbData != null)
            {
                children = new ArrayList(dbData.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < dbData.length; i++)
                {
                    NodeData d = new NodeData();
                    d.id = dbData[i][1];
                    d.name = dbData[i][1] + "Name";
                    children.add(d);
                    if ("R".equals(dbData[i][2]))
                        map.put(d, LEAF);
                }
            }
            else
                children = new ArrayList(0);

            map.put(s.id, children);       
        }

        return children;
    }

    private String[][] getChildren(String parent_uid){
        String sql = "select parent_uid,child_uid,child_type from stress_groups_mapping "
              + " where parent_uid="+ parent_uid
              +" order by parent_uid, child_uid";

        return Util.getTableData(sql);
    }

    public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object value)
    {
    }

    public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l)
    {
        listeners.add(TreeModelListener.class, l);
    }

    public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l)
    {
        listeners.remove(TreeModelListener.class, l);
    }

    public Object clone()
    {
        try
        {
            StressGroupModel clone = (StressGroupModel)super.clone();

            clone.listeners = new EventListenerList();

            clone.map = new HashMap(map);

            return clone;
        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e)
        {
            throw new InternalError();
        }
    }

}
```

- Here is how I create the tree

> public createTree{
>
> ```
> JFrame f = new JFrame("Tree Dragging Tester");
>           DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new Object());
>           jtree = new JTree(new StressGroupModel());
>           TreeWillExpandListener treeWillExpandListener = new TreeWillExpandListener() {
>                 public void treeWillCollapse(TreeExpansionEvent treeExpansionEvent)
>                     throws ExpandVetoException {
>
>
>                 }
>
>                 public void treeWillExpand(TreeExpansionEvent treeExpansionEvent) throws ExpandVetoException {
>                     TreePath path = treeExpansionEvent.getPath();
>                     Object node =  path.getLastPathComponent();
>                     ((StressGroupModel)jtree.getModel()).getChildCount(node);
>                   }
>
>
>           };
>
>           jtree.addTreeWillExpandListener(treeWillExpandListener);
>
>           f.getContentPane().add(jtree, BorderLayout.CENTER);
>           f.setSize(300, 200);
>           f.setVisible(true);
> }
> ```

- Here is how I save the expanded state

> Enumeration paths = jtree.getExpandedDescendants(new
>   TreePath(jtree.getModel().getRoot()));

- Do insert/update/delete DB stuffs
- Now re-initialize the model and add back to JTree (so it picks latest
  values from DB)
- Now I loop and call expand to expand the nodes that user expanded
  before he clicked the button but alas it stays collapsed :(

> jtree.setModel(new StressGroupModel());
>             while (paths.hasMoreElements()) {
>
> ```
>             TreePath treePath = (TreePath) paths.nextElement();
>
>             try {
>
>             jtree.expandPath(treePath);
>             jtree.setSelectionPath(treePath);
>
>             }
>             catch(Exception ex){
>
>             }
>
>         }
> ```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.

Need an equals method and hashCode in my NodeData class, problem was internally after setting the new Model when I was trying to expand the path the equals returned false as default implementation of equals does a "shallow compare" i.e. only compares references, I had to override the hashCode and equals method and did a "Deep compare" in equals method.

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar issue with a custom node class - it turns out my `equals` method wasn't quite right.

Comment: Wow. I have spent hours and couldn't understand why expandPath() doesn't work. It was really frustrating to visit so many forums and read the same advices: (use "expandPath(), setSelectionPath()" and so on). But it simply didn't work. Thanks!!!